# Ruby beginner - using /modifying existing gems in single project

Tags: ruby, rubygems

As the title states, I'm a beginner in Ruby.

My project uses 2 existing gems - which I want to modify.
I've forked the gems on GitHub and put them as modules in my repo and they show up as a subdirectory.

I've tried researching this, but I keep on getting lost - I'm thinking I'm missing some basic concepts/knowledge here.

My questions:

1. Am I going about this right/wrong?
2. Is it even possible to include the code of those (forked) gems in my actual project, or should I update them separately and just use them as actual gems with `require` (this seems very cumbersome)
3. If these gems are part of my project, how do I use them properly, I assume I don't need the `require` piece? If not, how do I access/use them?

Thanks!

BTW, using Ruby 1.9.2-p194 on Ubuntu with RubyMine as the IDE.

Comment: How are you modifying them? Can you just monkey patch them?

Answer (score 2):

1. Probably wrong. Ruby is a very flexible language, and has what are called *open classes*. This means that you can open up and change classes at run-time. Doing this on an external library is called *monkey patching*. So instead of having to replicate all of the code you want to stay consistent, you can just modify the classes and override any methods you want. 
   A simple example:

   ```
   class Fixnum
     def is_multiple_of_three?
       self % 3 == 0
     end
   end
   ```

   However, if the changes you want are really significant, it could make sense to fork the gem.
2. I recommend the `bundler` gem. This will let you make a `Gemfile` which lists all of your dependencies. You can list a github repository as a source for the gem, like so:

   `gem 'gem_name_here', :git => 'git://github.com/username_here/gem_name_here.git'`

   and then run `bundle install` to install your dependencies.
3. If you install the gems with bundler, it acts just like any other gem you have installed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think the monkey patching is a good idea, however I think my modifications to the existing projects will be too big for that - so I decided to fork them.

As to using the bundler - if I understand you correctly, I would make my modifications to the forked project separately, and then use them as GEMS in my own project?